# How to prevent duplication entry within certain time?

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a php program for our cleaning services company, we sent one cleaner twice a day, I want to limit the entry. If the cleaner inserted twice next entry should give this message "This cleaner is fully booked". I am using a calendar type of booking.
My insertion code is:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO bookings ( uid, empname, date, custname, cleaner, address) VALUES ('$uid', '$empname', '00:00:00', '$_post[custname]', '$_post[cleaner]', '$_post[address]')";
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: That's what unique indexes are for.

Comment: a) what have you tried so far? b) **don't** use `mysql` functions, they are deprecated and in PHP7 **removed**. use `PDO` or `mysqli` instead. c) your code is vulnerable to **SQL Injection**! - imagine someone posting a value like `'; DROP TABLE bookings; --` - use parameterized statements to protect yourself.

Comment: If I understood ur question, you can just use a unique value of your inserted data for each entry to get num_rows from the database and if it's bigger or equal to 2, you can show the message ! EX :" SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE uid = $uid"; Then, MySQL_num_rows (however you should never use MySQL_ in your code ! it's not secure and out of date !)

Comment: Hey bro, First, thank you for your notes, I am not a professional programmer I've taught my self from the Internet, if you helped me I will learn more.

Comment: Thanks @Soheyl, I will try that.

Comment: Don't be taught on me guys I am not an expert. It's my hobby!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to check the old records for the cleaner on the particular date. Use the following script to get the old records with the date:

```
$prevRecordsQuery= "SELECT COUNT(*) AS records FROM `bookings` WHERE `date` = $date AND `cleaner` = '$_post[cleaner]'";

$prevRecords = mysql_query($query);

if($prevRecords)
      echo "This cleaner is fully booked";
else{
     $query = "INSERT INTO bookings ( uid, empname, date, custname, cleaner, address) VALUES ('$uid', '$empname', '00:00:00', '$_post[custname]', '$_post[cleaner]', '$_post[address]')";
     $result = mysql_query($query);

}
```

Comment: Thank you, Parantap Parashar.

Comment: No problem. Always happy to help :)